# Laplace Transformation of piecewise-defined function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laplace-transform

So I‘m supposed to do the laplace transformation on the followimg Funktion:
[The task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pbcv.jpg)

This is what I got:
[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru2Vy.jpg)

Is there anything that I did wrong? How do I get to a) which is the right option?

Comment: Which definition of Laplace transform are you using? The usual definition is over the positive real line, in which case the behavior of $f(x)$ for negative $x$ is irrelevant.

Comment: We are using the usual definition. Should I try to solve it with the actual Integral definition?

Comment: You should type the content of the images into your post.  Among other reasons, this will make your question easier to be found when searching.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Laplace transform? It looks like the Fourier transform to me (which, I know, it's a general version).

Comment: I just used some general rules regarding the laplace transform. But why do you think that I‘m using the fourier transformation?

Comment: What I’m suspicious of is that both Heaviside functions are treated the same, aside from the shifts being different. But $H(x+1)=1$ for all positive $x$, which is all that should matter for the usual (one-sided) Laplace transform.

Comment: Nvm apparently the solution is for the fourier transform Sean was right